# How to send data from android application to MYsql server?

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-asynctask, server

I am facing a problem when I send data to server, unfortunately closing my application. I don't know why it will come like this. I tried but unable to resolve. Please some one help me.
It is always showing error in the  **new CreateUser().execute();**,**class CreateUser extends AsyncTask {**, **pDialog.show();**,**int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);  if (success == 1)** {. These lines i am getting error. Also i have JSON parser class

```
public class JSONParser {
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}

/*public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        // Extract data from the response.
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        // Open an inputStream with the data content.
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
        String line = null;

        // Build the string until null.
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        // Close the input stream.
        is.close();
        // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // Return the JSON Object.
    return jObj;

}*/
```

}

Here is my code:

```
public class ConsentActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

SharedPreferences sharedpref_user;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

String result;

private static String url_new_user = "http://192.167.1.123:8080/pharmacy/services/user/createUser";

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";


@InjectView(R.id.btn_next5) protected Button next_Edit;
@InjectView(R.id.checkBox_consent) protected CheckBox checkbox_consent;

@InjectView(R.id.close_icon5) protected TextView close_text_consent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.consent_info);

    sharedpref_user = getSharedPreferences("UserMgmt", 0);
    editor = sharedpref_user.edit();

    //text justification
    String htmlText = "<html><body style=\"text-align:justify\" \"> %s </body></Html>";
    String myData = "<font color='#035e85'>"+"All copyright, trade marks, design rights, patents and other intellectual property rights (registered and unregistered) in and on YGT Online Services and YGT Content belong to the YGT and/or third parties (which may include you or other users). The YGT reserves all of its rights in YGT Content and YGT Online Services. Nothing in the Terms grants you a right or licence to use any trade mark, design right or copyright owned or controlled by the YGT or any other third party except as expressly provided in the Terms.\n"+"</font>";

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView_consent_txt_justify);
    webView.loadData(String.format(htmlText, myData), "text/html", "utf-8");
    webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
    webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    next_Edit.setEnabled(false);

    checkbox_consent.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if ( isChecked )
            {
                next_Edit.setEnabled(true);
                result="true";
            }
            else{
                next_Edit.setEnabled(false);
                result="false";
            }
        }
    });

    Typeface font_close5 = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf" );
    TextView personal_close=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.close_icon5);
    personal_close.setTypeface(font_close5);

    close_text_consent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        }
    });

    Boolean consent_check = checkbox_consent.isChecked();
    //Toast.makeText(TermsConditions.this, "result:" + tc_check, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    editor.putBoolean("ChkBoxConsent", consent_check);
    editor.commit();


    //next button1
    next_Edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new CreateUser().execute();

        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
}

class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ConsentActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Registering New User..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("UserMgmt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String Firstname = pref.getString("FName", "");
        String Lastname = pref.getString("LName", "");
        String Userid = pref.getString("UserId", "");
        String Password = pref.getString("Password", "");
        String Repassword = pref.getString("RePassword", "");

        String Idproof_typ=pref.getString("IdType","");
        String Idproof_number=pref.getString("IdNumber","");
        String Dob=pref.getString("DOB","");
        String Gender=pref.getString("Gender","");
        String Email=pref.getString("Email","");
        String Mobile_number=pref.getString("Mobile","");
        String Country_code=pref.getString("CountryCode","");
        String Landline=pref.getString("LandLine","");

        String Country=pref.getString("Country","");
        String State=pref.getString("State","");
        String Address=pref.getString("Address","");
        String Pincod=pref.getString("Pincode","");

        boolean Tc_chk_state = pref.getBoolean("ChkBoxTC", true);

        boolean Consent_chk_state = pref.getBoolean("ChkBoxConsent", true);

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

       // params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", Userid));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstName", Firstname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastName", Lastname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", Password));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("newPassword", Repassword));

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("identityType", Idproof_typ));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("identityNumber", Idproof_number));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dob", Dob));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender", Gender));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emailId", Email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobileNumber", Mobile_number));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stdCode", Country_code));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("landlineNumber", Landline));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("countryCode", Country));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stateCode", State));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("addr", Address));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("zipcode", Pincod));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_new_user,
                "POST", params);

              //  Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created a user
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create user
                Log.d("failed to create user", json.toString());

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

   protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

   }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
}
```

please check my error logcat

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ***mtest.you.com.pharmacy.ConsentActivity$CreateUser.doInBackground(ConsentActivity.java:191)
        at mtest.you.com.pharmacy.ConsentActivity$CreateUser.doInBackground(ConsentActivity.java:123)***
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-08 17:27:52.933    3873-3873/mtest.tag.com.pharmacy E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity mtest.yougo.com.pharmatnt.ConsentActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{421a9280 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:422)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:250)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
        at mtest.yougo.com.pharmatnt.ConsentActivity$CreateUser.onPreExecute(ConsentActivity.java:132)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
        at mtest.you.com.pharmacy.ConsentActivity$3.onClick(ConsentActivity.java:112)

at mtest.you.com.pharmacy.ConsentActivity$CreateUser.onPreExecute(ConsentActivity.java:132)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
        at mtest.you.com.pharmacy.ConsentActivity$3.onClick(ConsentActivity.java:112)
```

Comment: at which line do you get the error?

Comment: new CreateUser().execute();...class CreateUser extends AsyncTask {, pDialog.show();...int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);... if (success == 1) { ... these four lines i am getting errors...

Comment: OMG, do you really know how java works? `if(method == "POST"){`

Comment: i followed one tutorial...if any error is there please let me know...

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/800703/Connecting-your-Android-app-to-your-WAMP-server   .... i followed this tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you try to exit your activity from a background thread. One solution would be this.

Declare your JSONObject at the beginning of the CreateUser class:

```
JSONObject json;
```

In doInBackground() replace:

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_new_user,
            "POST", params);
```

with:

```
json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_new_user,
            "POST", params);
```

Move this code in onPostExecute:

```
try {
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

        if (success == 1) {
            // successfully created a user
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // closing this screen
            finish();
        } else {
            // failed to create user
            Log.d("failed to create user", json.toString());

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Finally, you should have this in the CreateUser class:

```
class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    JSONObject json;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ConsentActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Registering New User..");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("UserMgmt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String Firstname = pref.getString("FName", "");
    String Lastname = pref.getString("LName", "");
    String Userid = pref.getString("UserId", "");
    String Password = pref.getString("Password", "");
    String Repassword = pref.getString("RePassword", "");

    String Idproof_typ=pref.getString("IdType","");
    String Idproof_number=pref.getString("IdNumber","");
    String Dob=pref.getString("DOB","");
    String Gender=pref.getString("Gender","");
    String Email=pref.getString("Email","");
    String Mobile_number=pref.getString("Mobile","");
    String Country_code=pref.getString("CountryCode","");
    String Landline=pref.getString("LandLine","");

    String Country=pref.getString("Country","");
    String State=pref.getString("State","");
    String Address=pref.getString("Address","");
    String Pincod=pref.getString("Pincode","");

    boolean Tc_chk_state = pref.getBoolean("ChkBoxTC", true);

    boolean Consent_chk_state = pref.getBoolean("ChkBoxConsent", true);

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

   // params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", Userid));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstName", Firstname));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastName", Lastname));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", Password));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("newPassword", Repassword));

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("identityType", Idproof_typ));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("identityNumber", Idproof_number));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dob", Dob));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender", Gender));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emailId", Email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobileNumber", Mobile_number));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stdCode", Country_code));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("landlineNumber", Landline));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("countryCode", Country));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stateCode", State));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("addr", Address));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("zipcode", Pincod));

    json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_new_user,
            "POST", params);

          //  Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());


    return null;
}

  protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

  }

protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog once done
    pDialog.dismiss();
    try {
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

        if (success == 1) {
            // successfully created a user
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // closing this screen
            finish();
        } else {
            // failed to create user
            Log.d("failed to create user", json.toString());

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: boss it is giving 2 errors at mtest.yougo.com.pharmatnt.ConsentActivity$CreateUser.onPostExecute(ConsentActivity.java:203)--->int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            at mtest.yougo.com.pharmatnt.ConsentActivity$CreateUser.onPostExecute(ConsentActivity.java:123)--->  class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

Answer (score 0):

```
class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    int success=0;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ConsentActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Registering New User..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("UserMgmt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String Firstname = pref.getString("FName", "");
        String Lastname = pref.getString("LName", "");
        String Userid = pref.getString("UserId", "");
        String Password = pref.getString("Password", "");
        String Repassword = pref.getString("RePassword", "");

        String Idproof_typ=pref.getString("IdType","");
        String Idproof_number=pref.getString("IdNumber","");
        String Dob=pref.getString("DOB","");
        String Gender=pref.getString("Gender","");
        String Email=pref.getString("Email","");
        String Mobile_number=pref.getString("Mobile","");
        String Country_code=pref.getString("CountryCode","");
        String Landline=pref.getString("LandLine","");

        String Country=pref.getString("Country","");
        String State=pref.getString("State","");
        String Address=pref.getString("Address","");
        String Pincod=pref.getString("Pincode","");

        boolean Tc_chk_state = pref.getBoolean("ChkBoxTC", true);

        boolean Consent_chk_state = pref.getBoolean("ChkBoxConsent", true);

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

       // params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", Userid));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstName", Firstname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastName", Lastname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", Password));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("newPassword", Repassword));

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("identityType", Idproof_typ));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("identityNumber", Idproof_number));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dob", Dob));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender", Gender));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emailId", Email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobileNumber", Mobile_number));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stdCode", Country_code));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("landlineNumber", Landline));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("countryCode", Country));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stateCode", State));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("addr", Address));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("zipcode", Pincod));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_new_user,
                "POST", params);

               Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        try {
             success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

   protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

   }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created a user
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create user
                Log.d("failed to create user", json.toString());

            }
    }

}
}
```

check  "Create Response" in log an post it to trace out your json response.